# How to prevent table columns from being misaligned on 100% zoom?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is rendered from a gridview in ASP.NET. I'm using CSS to create scroll bars on the table. I notice when I decrease the zoom everything fits and aligns properly at say 67%, but when at 100%, the header columns are misaligned and also the second to last row. What could be causing this?

I've tried setting `min-width` on the `thead` but doesn't seem to have any effect.

```css
table.grdPCO {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

table.grdPCO thead,
table.grdPCO tbody {
  display: block;
}

table.grdPCO thead {
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

table.grdPCO tbody {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table.grdPCO tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

table.grdPCO tr td,
table.grdPCO tr th {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<table class="grdPCO">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like the columns to align up no matter the zoom level.

Comment: Please provide your HTML so we can get the full picture of what is happening + reproduce it.

Comment: Added the html to my question.

Comment: Do you notice the effect happening here? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mayhjbg/) It all seems fine to me is all

Comment: Instead of making the table no longer act like a table, if you want the whole table to scroll, you should just wrap the table in a div and make the div scrollable. Much easier: https://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/QWWOyXr

Comment: Unfortuntately, I need the header to be fixed, that's why am doing it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table.grdPCO {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

table.grdPCO thead,
table.grdPCO tbody {
  display: block;
}

table.grdPCO thead {
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

table.grdPCO tbody {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table.grdPCO tr {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
  display: flex;
}

table.grdPCO tr td,
table.grdPCO tr th {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<table class="grdPCO">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think by adding `text-align: left` to all `tr` elements should fix it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect? My actual table is much larger, could that be why?

Comment: This seems to work, if I make the `th` width 40px. However, the header is not fixed, it also scrolls with the table content. How do I make sure the header stays fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fixed_header {
  width: 800px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fixed_header tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
  display: block;
}

.fixed_header thead {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

.fixed_header th,
.fixed_header td {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed_header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>35</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```